# Bindings not working in WPF window user control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have this User Control XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProj.Dialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:shell="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/shell"
        mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Foos}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="ASd" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

and the corresponding code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace MyProj
{
    public partial class Dialog : Window
    {
        public Dialog() : base()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //DataContext = this;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> Foos = new ObservableCollection<string> { "foo", "bar" };
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that for some reason the `ItemsControl` does not display anything. The odd thing is that I don't even get binding warnings in the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In WPF, the [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) component of a binding can only refer to properties (or property paths), not fields. Try encapsulating your collection in a property:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> foos = 
    new ObservableCollection<string> { "foo", "bar" };

public ObservableCollection<string> Foos
{
    get { return foos; }
}
```

Also, you need to uncomment the line where you set the `DataContext`:

```
DataContext = this;
```

Comment: you can also bind to fields and specify the properties in the XAML.  For the case of a simple collection there is nothing to do but if you wanted to bind to a class object (field) with a `Foo` property you would simply set `myControl.DataContext = someObject` and set the binding in the XAML to `{Binding Path = Foo}`.  The data context of the control becomes the object and the binding path routes to its `Foo` property.

Comment: @J…: Yes. There’s a similar approach for accessing elements using `ElementName=` syntax. But the `Path=` part of the binding must reference properties.

Comment: yes, except for the case of simple objects like ObservableCollections (as in my answer) where the path is implied and does not need to link to an explicit property.  In my example the binding is directly to a private collection (I guess you could say that the property in question is the publically exposed items in the collection).

Comment: The difference, I suppose, comes down to complexity.  For a simple window it may suffice to just say `DataContext = this;` and set the context for the entire window to the entire class.  The other option allows you to be much more specific - each element gets a narrow DataContext reflecting the exact type of object it is to be bound to.  Also, you may not want your class to publically expose properties for objects or data you want to display.  In such cases it is better to set the components' DataContext to a private object.

Answer (score 3):

You can also bind fields (easiest if you name the component, but you need to reference it somehow) :

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="myItems">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

with

```
private ObservableCollection<string> Foos = 
  new ObservableCollection<string> { "foo", "bar" };

public Dialog() : base
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myItems.DataContext = Foos;
}
```

This can be more flexible than hard-coding the binding in the XAML since you are not binding to a specific property of your class but rather to any object which exposes the correct properties.  Supposing you had a number of collections, you could easily display any of them in the ItemsControl simply by changing (programmatically) its DataContext to whatever collection you wished to display.